# Pattern matching with a map inside a map (Elixir)

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I have the following function working in an Elixir app:

```
  def emojify(%Conv{status: 200, resp_headers: resp_headers} = conv) do
    body = if resp_headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json", do: conv.resp_body, else: "" <> "\n\n" <> conv.resp_body <> "\n\n" <> ""
  
    %{ conv | resp_body: body }
  end

  def emojify(%Conv{} = conv), do: conv
```

I'd like to refactor it to eliminate the need for the `if` inside it. I imagine that the way to do it is through pattern matching the content-type inside the `resp_headers`, but that would be pattern matching of a map inside a map (a struct inside a map to be more precise, but I don't think this detail is relevant in this case), and I'm not sure how to do that.

I was trying something like `def emojify(%Conv{status: 200, resp_headers: %{"Content-Type" => "application/json"}} = conv)`, but I understand that this would only work if `resp_headers` has only `"Content-Type" => "application/json"` inside it, and that isn't the case. So how could I accomplish this?

Comment: Please remember, that HTTP headers usually are case insensitive and also can occur multiple times. Therefore the libarary you are using might actually not use a map at all for the headers but wrap them in a struct that implements `Access`.

Comment: For now, I'm just building things from scratch to understand the "Elixir way", so I'm not using a library and it's not an app for production. But good to know, I'll remember!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that this would only work if resp_headers has only `"Content-Type" => "application/json"` inside it

This assumption is wrong. The map matches if the fields in the match are presented in the input *and* all pinned variables are matched. You have no pinned variables, so you are OK.

Match to the empty map is frequently used instead of `is_map(map)` guard as `foo(%{} = map) do ...`

```rb
%{} = %{foo: 42, bar: :baz} # success

# and also
%{foo: foo} = %{foo: 42, bar: :baz} # success
foo
#⇒ 42
```

That said, the answer would be

```rb
def emojify(%Conv{
    status: 200,
    resp_headers: %{"Content-Type" => "application/json"}} = conv),
  do: %{ conv | resp_body: conv.resp_body }

def emojify(%Conv{status: 200} = conv),
  do: %{ conv | resp_body: "" <> "\n\n" <> conv.resp_body <> "\n\n" <> ""}

def emojify(%Conv{} = conv), do: conv
```

---

*Sidenote:* example with pinned variables.

```rb
%{foo: 42} = %{foo: 42, bar: :baz} # success

foo = 42
%{foo: ^foo} = %{foo: 42, bar: :baz} # success

%{foo: ^foo} = %{foo: :incorrect, bar: :baz} # raises
```

Comment: Just pointing out in case someone have the doubt: in the `def emojify(%Conv{status: 200} = conv)` the returned value should be the map `%{ conv | resp_body: "" <> "\n\n" <> conv.resp_body <> "\n\n" <> "" }`. But I understood and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Fixed in the answer, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can pattern-match like so

```
def emojify( %{status: 200, resp_headers: %{"Content-Type" => "application/json" } } = conv
) do
    %{ conv | resp_body: conv.resp_body }    
   end
   def emojify(%{status: 200} = conv) do
    %{ conv | resp_body: "" <> "\n\n" <> conv.resp_body <> "\n\n" <> "" }
   end
   def emojify(conv), do: conv
```

You can always pattern-match values of specific keys in a map or a struct

For more check this out [joyofelixir](https://joyofelixir.com/6-pattern-matching).